# Android Google Map API:Force Close Error

Tags: android, google-maps

I have received forced closed error message on running the [sample code of Google API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview).Is update a project is a solution to this type of project? If so then how to update project on window.The method given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559336/how-to-update-old-android-project-for-the-updates-in-new-android-sdk-tools) don't work on my case.

Here is code

Filename:HelloGoogleMaps.java

```
    package com.hellogooglemaps.practices;

    import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
    import android.os.Bundle;


    public class HelloGoogleMaps extends MapActivity {
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
   protected boolean isRouteDisplayed(){
    return false;
}

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    MapView mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

}
@Override
protected boolean isLocationDisplayed(){
    return true;
}
}
```

HelloGoogleMaps Manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".HelloGoogleMapsActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>        
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".HelloGoogleMaps" android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
</application>
```

main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/mapview"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:clickable="true"
             android:apiKey="0_hYeORLgQUROOOr_RXN2TWG2u2pCDoBYfLCV_w"
             />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you had mentioned in your code, You have only one Activity called `HelloGoogleMaps` and in your `AndroidManifest` you have declared two activities!! your `HelloGoogleMapsActivity` is useless. You are getting the error because you set HelloGoogleMapsActivity as the Launcher activity and this activity don't even exist!!

**Solution:**
change your `AndroidManifest.xml` like that and you will get your app work if you had managed to get the apikey for your map correctly:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:name=".HelloGoogleMaps" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>        
    </activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
</application>
```

Comment: I had used that above the application

Comment: thanks a lot for your helps. I think problem occurred isn't because of activity.When I delete old project and do the same job on new one its works.I don't know whats going inside.

Comment: @NarayanKandel that's do to your activity declaration in Manifest, because when you create a new project it will cretae for you an activity with 
<intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

Comment: @NarayanKandel and you have changed the name and add the new activity to the manifest

Comment: @NarayanKandel you can reproduce the same problem with same code by copy/paste an you will find that what I was talking about is completely true

Comment: this code also work on my case...
        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".HelloGoogleMapsActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category       android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>   cont...

Comment: <activity android:name=".HelloGoogleMaps" android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    </application>

on my new project ...

Comment: @npkand your class name in that case is HelloGoogleMapsActivity.java in your new project otherwise you won't get it work

Answer (score 0):

After facing `Force close Error` many time what I have found is that these type of error is so common and come due to the `undefined behavioral`.Like when we declare Button and without assigning the view on it we use it on another function. It is also appear due to not handling the exception correctly. or Due to unavailable of resource your are trying to access in emulator like contact number. Best method to solve these type of problem is using log and printing some message on place where we feel confusing and using logcat.

In above case I had received force close error due to undefined behavior in *HelloGoogleMapsActivity* class